# clutch installation

Tags: clutch, mazda, miata

I am installing a new clutch in a 1999 Miata. When putting the tranny back in, I can get it in very easily, but it won't go all the way, it only lacks about half an inch. I can get bolts started but I"M afraid to use the bolts to draw it in further. Am I just pushing against the 'fingers' on the clutch plate? I have put on a new fly wheel, disc, pressure plate and release bearing. Thanks for your help.

Comment: This might be an obvious question, but was a clutch alignment tool ***carefully*** used to align the friction disk?

Comment: no, you would not ordinarily be pushing against the pressure plate since the throw out should be fully released.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 a very good question - I always used to line up the clutch plate centre to the flywheel centre by eye - and with a Landrover gearbox and its weight it was no joke if you got it wrong...  One thing the OP could try is to have the 'box in gear and gently turn the output shaft to rotate the input shaft as if the teeth are butting against each other that is the missing half-inch...

Comment: @dave3515 - StackExchange's first rule is [Be Nice](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice). I'm sorry you felt I was not following that policy. Please understand, from your description of the problem, your friction disk is *not lined up*. The last 1/2" is the tip of the transmission not entering the pilot bearing. I was asking the obvious question, before assuming something else. Is it possible to do it without an alignment tool? Sure, but the odds are not in your favor, especially if you're working on a transmission you've never dealt with before. I'm here to help, not offend you.

Comment: @dave3515 and Dave, you were right in not using the bolts to draw it in - that would damage the centre plate aka friction disc. So, it will go in, it's either the teeth or that pilot bearing - Oh and good luck with it - patience and a cup of tea...

Comment: @dave3515 another thought - and no offence intended - but is the centre plate the correct way round? One side will have " flywheel-side" stamped on it - if it is the wrong way round that may be the issue. We have had boxes go in easily, but for each one of the easy ones there are two that are difficult...

Comment: @SolarMike - Good point on friction disk orientation.

Comment: @dave3515 I have edited Paulster2's comment for clarity - I don't think he was suggesting that your question was stupid, but that the question he was asking in response is.

Comment: WRT what NickC said ... spot on. Actually a good question on your end ... mine was self-depreciating. Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 5):

If it's only the last half inch I doubt it's the clutch disc splines - the splines would have much more engagement depth than 1/2".  However, the disc needs to be clamped accurately to about 50 thousandths centricity to make certain the bevel on the input shaft tip can enter the pilot bearing.

Like @Paulster2 mentioned, pilot bearing is far more likely, and the *easy* (fingers crossed) @Solar Mike solution hopefully is to have a helper spin the driveshaft while in a low gear, while you try and get the tranny to seat flush (wiggle-shake-wiggle and then some).  This might allow the input shaft tip to rotate into the pilot bearing or bushing.

As an aside, I always buy the complete clutch kit from a vendor like Sachs or Luk that includes the pressure plate, friction, possibly throwout and/or pilot bearing, but *always the plastic splined alignment dowel*.  And it's your to keep!  Not to brag, but after 4 decades I have accumulated probably 40 or more of these different distinct tools.  I have a pegboard display that I hang them on in my shop, that really amounts to nothing more than a gearhead mechanic's trophy wall.

Another possibility is that you have created a burr on alignment dowel(s) or mashed the lip of the aluminum dowel receiver hole on the bell housing, which is quite easy to do while wrestling the tranny in place. *How do I know??*  If you're lucky you can see/reach this and dress it lightly with a file.  Unlucky and you may have to pull the transmission, check, fix, and start over.

Best of luck.

Comment: it was Paulster2 who pointed out the pilot bearing, but good write-up

Comment: @SolarMike  Fixed that, Paulster mentioned it, yet you provided the solution I would have used and suggested.  Perhaps among the three of us there's a clutch or two (or 70) in our past??

Comment: Let’s hope the OP gets a result and yes, clutches on cars, landies,  hgv’s and tractors...

Comment: @Solar mike This is one of those I wish the OP would respond with whatever happened.  [sigh]   Closure, darn it.  I want it; I need it...

Comment: So, that’s you , @Paulster2 and me then.. orhers as well, not doubt...